# invoking a static method with an instance of the class. why?

Tags: c#, instance, static-methods

This is a small snippet of code that I found. 
when we make a call

```
    object.Max(s=>s.Length)
```

why do we need a static method?

```
    public static TResult Max<TSource, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
    {
        return source.Select(selector).Max();
    }
```

please update the question title. I couldnot abstract it well.

Comment: The code posted makes no sense at all. I doubt it even compiles. What is the intend of the code? To find the max value of a collection?

Comment: unfortunately, yes. documentation of the method Max() is (Invokes a transform function on each element of a generic sequence and returns the maximum resulting value.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an *extension method* (via the `this` modifier on the first parameter). The `obj.` is passed in as the first argument instead. So:

```
obj.Max()
```

is identical to:

```
DeclaringType.Max(obj, s=>s.Length)
```

But note that *genuine* instance methods always take precedence during static analysis, so if the object had a suitable `Max` method *itself*, it would be chosen instead of the extension method.

Extension methods must be static methods on non-nested static classes.